# Opening a browser within native mobile app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile-application

I'm developing a native mobile app for Android and iOS using PhoneGap.I have a requirement to open a hyperlink in my applcation. I don't want the user to navigate away from my application by opening it in device's browser. Also I need to reuse the cookies that I set in my native app in the application that will be opened from the URL.
How do I open link in a browser (which has Address bar) **within my native app**? I have seen in iOS apps like GMail, Facebook app etc, a browser can be opened within the application.
Could you please help me to implement this? Please let me know if my question is not clear or need any further details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin called Childbrowser (as Kerri suggest). It exists for several platforms (iOS, Android...) and is used very widely.

Take a look here: 
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is create a "WebView" view controller which has properties such as URL and Title. The view it controls is simply a UIWebView and when you want to open a page inside your app you do something like:

```
WebViewController *view = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView" bundle:nil];

view.passedURL = self.url;
view.title = self.nameLabel.text;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view];

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

[view release];
[navController release];
```

This slides it up from the bottom and loads the web page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll surely give a try. We need to do that in platform independent manner.

Answer (score 0):

I use the ChildBrowser plugin -- it essentially does what @bipolarpants is doing, but already has the interface with icons built. That's for iOS... I can't help you with Android. :-(